# scalar command in context.Database.SqlQuery<double?> vs SQL in Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a script that i run from EF 6.1 context:

```
using (var context = new Entities())
{
    context.Database.CommandTimeout = 120;
    var result  = context.Database.SqlQuery<double?>(
        sqlCommandString,
        new SqlParameter("since", since),
        new SqlParameter("until", until),
        new SqlParameter("p", p)
        ).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I noticed that if i run the script inside Management Studio with the exact same parameters it has an execution time of 40 ms whereas running it in a console app using the code above, it throws a timeout exception.

The connection string is correct, other scripts run fine (slower but at least they return).

What am I missing? Is there another way of executing a scalar command using EF without actually mapping a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executng SQL directly from code, check the tabs and spaces inside the script.

If the code is multiline and you keep it indented, all the tabs and white spaces are send with the command. Running the code from EF wraps it in sp_executesql and with all the tabs and spaces that becomes a mess.

**Bad**:

```
if(true)
{
    if(true)
    {
        string sqlCommand = @"
            SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT * FROM tblA
            ) A
        ";
    }
}
```

**Good**:

```
if(true)
{
    if(true)
    {
        string sqlCommand = 
@"
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tblA
) A
";
    }
}
```